# Javascript in preventing a form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I prevent a submit and reverse it again and allow it to submit after I did my condition on it. Can you please help me? Hope you understand my question here.

Comment: Please share the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.preventDefault();`

```
if(condition){
    e.preventDefault();
}else{
    //do what you want
}
```

Comment: what if a already called the preventdefault on top,how can i reverse it after?

Comment: @Nethan just call it inside an if statement, you can't reverse it outside unless you rebind the function.

Comment: call a function on form submit, do your validation there and trigger submit if the condition pass.

If preventDefault is already set, then try this:

    $('form').submit( function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        //later you decide you want to submit
        $(this).unbind('submit').submit()
    });

Answer (score 0):

Change your `submit` button to normal `button` & perform your condition check using `.click()` event

```
$('#button_id').click(function(e){
    if(condition_satisfied)
    {
        $('#form_id').submit();
    }
});
```